# Default implementation of behaviour

Tags: c#, oop

Scenario

There are three types of Vehicle

1. Vehicle who moves on Land.
2. Vehicle who moves on Water.
3. Vehicle who moves in Air.

There is a common behavior in all type of vehicle, All can move. But the way they move is completely different (Medium on which vehicle move).

It means,All Vehicles have common behavior (Move) but completely unique implementation.

Question 1

Can we have a base class with a virtual function (Move) with some default implementation in this case, as all vehicle has completely different implementation ?

OR

Will  Abstract class be good approach for this design as we don't have any default implementation ?

Question 2

Should we use abstract method when we don't have default implementation ? (Just to confirm for other scenarios)

Comment: Is it OOP assignment/homework ?

Comment: @Habib, Yes, It is Oops related.

Comment: The design of your classes totally dependens on the context and the way you plan to use them. So your question cannot be answered without knowing the context. You might end up with a structure of classes without any inheritance at all (always perefer composition over inheritance) or you might end up with a direct inheritance chain.

Comment: If you can define only interface of vehicle, why won't you go with interface? If there's some implementation then you should go with abstract class that will implement common methods, implement default implementation for virtual methods and have `abstract` methods that is different for every derived class. In another words, it depends. So there's no correct answer to this question, IMO. Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: @PLB What value interface adds if in both case(Abstract and Interface)i have to implement Move method ?

Comment: @MazharKhan, since its a homework, you should go through [virtual methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(v=vs.110).aspx) and [abstract methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.110).aspx) with respect to C# and see what you need for your situation

Comment: @MazharKhan Main difference in this case would be that class can implement several interfaces but can inherit only one class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly vague question, and I think you're possibly doing homework.

Firstly, a virtual method will allow you to write some default behavior which all sub classes will inherit, but have the option to replace with their own.

Basically, you need to ask yourself, is there any common BEHAVIOR, as apposed to common interface?

Think of a music player. What is the interface? Lets go with stop, fast forward, rewind and play.

That is a good example of an interface. All the default "behavior" is described by the name of the method.

the way a CD player would "play" is nothing like how an MP3 player would "play". The above would be examples of abstract methods.

If this is all of your required behavior, you don't need an abstract class, you need an interface.

However, now think of a button that is rewind till the beginning and play. This is a good example of a virtual method, and you will need an abstract class to implement it in. You can provide a default implementation based on the abstract methods you've already written, and it will just work (ignoring detecting the beginning of the track ;)). Additionally, sub classes have the ability to overwrite the behavior if they want to.

Answer to your question:

Question 1: I'd say no; Move should be abstract as there is no default implementation (although default implied behavior)

Question 2: Yes if you don't have default implementation, use abstract. Although, if you find that your class completely comprises of abstract methods, ask yourself if instead you would be better off to define an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1

Yes, Abstract class will be good approach for this design as we don't have any default implementation ?

Question 2

Yes, we use abstract method when we don't have default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have any `Vehicle` that is not `Land`, `Water` or `Air`, you probably want an `abstract` class.

Same for methods: if the implementation is always different (i.e. you always have to re-define the implementation), `abstract` is fine.

If there is no shared implementation, then interfaces would do the job.